# How do I fix this recurring "Error establishing a database connection" that I'm getting from a WordPress website?

Tags: database, wordpress, database-table, wordpress-database

I'm reaching out to seek assistance regarding a recurring issue I've been encountering with my WordPress website's database connection.

Problem Description:
Every time I attempt to access the backend or admin page of my website, I encounter an "Error Establishing a Database Connection" message. To address this issue, I've tried repairing the database tables using phpMyAdmin. Initially, after repairing the tables, the website functions properly. However, after approximately 8 hours or 1 day, the problem resurfaces.

Investigation Findings:
Upon further investigation using phpMyAdmin tools, I noticed that the `wp_options` table is exhibiting irregularities, resulting in a warning status. The scan/check result for the `wp_options` table is as follows:
Table: nonsmiey_wp233.wp9l_options
Warning
Found 32106 key parts. Should be: 32105
Status: OK

Temporary Fix:
Whenever I encounter the issue, repairing the specific table `nonsmiey_wp233.wp9l_options` resolves the problem temporarily, restoring the website's functionality. However, the issue recurs after some time.

Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on how to address this issue permanently. Despite my attempts to repair the database tables, the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or solutions to resolve this recurring database connection error.

Attached are relevant Images:
[image]